# Complex Integration - $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{x^5-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration

> ***Exercise :***
>
> *Show that :*
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{x^5-1} dx = \frac{4\pi}{5}\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{5}\bigg)$$

***Attempt :***

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-1}{x^5-1} dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1}dx $$

$$x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1=0 \Leftrightarrow x =  \{-(-1)^{1/5},(-1)^{2/5},-(-1)^{3/5},(-1)^{4/5} \}$$

So, the function $f(z) = \frac{1}{x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1}$  has poles  at the points :

$$\{-(-1)^{1/5},(-1)^{2/5},-(-1)^{3/5},(-1)^{4/5} \}$$

Now, I know you have to integrate through a closed curve $C$ and on a line $γ_R$ and then continue on with residues for the poles that reside in this curve, but I am stuck on how to apply it here and I also miss it a bit on how to split the integral for the *curve* and the *line*. Most examples I've saw get simpler due to the *even function* trick, but that cannot be applied here.

I would really appreciate a thorough solution and explanation, since I've just started working on *generalized integrals* and I have to clear my mind on them.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}$$ equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of residues at the poles in the upper half-plane.

Comment: The poles in the upper half plane are $\zeta_5=e^{2\pi i/5}$ and $\zeta_5^2$ and they are simple. Can you now determine the residues?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  So: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}dz = \int_{C} \frac{dz}{z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}dz = 2\pi i [Res(f(z),(-1)^{2/5}) + Res(f(z),(-1)^{4/5})] $, where $C$ is the *half-unit circle* in the upper plane ?

Comment: Your radius should be greater $1$. Otherwise, the singularities are on your curve. But then your right. You just need to compute your residues.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt Yep, true, just plotted it. So it's just a half-circle on the upper-half plane with radius $r>1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2250128/427792 this could be useful

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light It's already solved, but thanks ! No point as well to complicate it this much, since it's not a general form.

Comment: yeah agree jack's method using residues is lot easier

Comment: @Lelouch.D.Light The only problem is that none of these show straight-forward that the result is : $\frac{4\pi}{5}\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{5}\bigg)$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An integral of a rational function on the real line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2086427/an-integral-of-a-rational-function-on-the-real-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the upper part of the complex plane we get:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x-1}{x^5-1}dx=i2\pi Res(\frac{x-1}{x^5-1},e^{i2\pi/5})+ i2\pi Res(\frac{x-1}{x^5-1},e^{i4\pi/5})$

$\displaystyle = i2\pi\frac{x-1}{x^5-1}(x-e^{i2\pi/5})|_{x\to e^{i2\pi/5}}+ i2\pi\frac{x-1}{x^5-1}(x-e^{i4\pi/5})|_{x\to e^{i4\pi/5}} $

$\displaystyle =\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{\sin(\frac{\pi}{5})\sin(\frac{3\pi}{5})\sin(\frac{4\pi}{5})}=\frac{4\pi}{5}\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}$

Answer (score 7):

Brute force also helps:
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x-1}{x^5-1}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1}dx=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+x+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)}dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+x+\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}dx=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^2\left(x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{-1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)\left(x+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{-1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)}dx=$$
$$=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(x^2-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}x+1\right)\left(x^2+\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}x+1\right)}dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{x+\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}}{x^2+\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}x+1}-\frac{x-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}}{x^2-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}x+1}\right)dx=$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt5}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}}{x^2+\frac{\sqrt5+1}{2}x+1}-\frac{\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}}{x^2-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{2}x+1}\right)dx=$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4\sqrt5}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4}\right)^2+1-\frac{6+2\sqrt5}{16}}dx-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4\sqrt5}\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4}\right)^2+1-\frac{6-2\sqrt5}{16}}dx=$$
$$=\pi\left(\frac{\sqrt5+1}{4\sqrt5\sqrt{\frac{10-2\sqrt5}{16}}}-\frac{\sqrt5-1}{4\sqrt5\sqrt{\frac{10+2\sqrt5}{16}}}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt5}\left(\frac{\cos36^{\circ}}{\sin36^{\circ}}-\frac{\sin18^{\circ}}{\cos18^{\circ}}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{\pi\cos54^{\circ}}{\sqrt5\sin36^{\circ}\cos18^{\circ}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt5\cos18^{\circ}}.$$