How to factorize $x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$?
That day while solving the problem of MIT Bee Challenge Question, the OP sent one link of the questions of MIT Bee Final.
There one integral was there which was to find the value of $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1}dx$$
Now I just want to know that how can we factorize $$(x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$$
Let me explain how I tried to factorize $(x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$
I wrote
$(x^{2}+ax+b)(x^{2}+cx+d)=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$
Now I multiplied the Left Hand Side.
That is I got
$x^{4}+(a+c)x^{3}+(b+d+ac)x^{2}+(ad+bc)x+bd=x^{4}+x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1$
Therefore we can conclude that
$(a+c)=1$
$(b+d+ac)=1$
$(ad+bc)=1$
$bd=1$
Now I am unable to solve these $4$ equations to find the values of $a,b,c,d$.
Please explain me how to find the values of $a,b,c,d$ from the above $4$ equations ?

Have you tried multiplying by $x-1$ in the numerator and the denominator?

An easier way to find a decomposition is to  find the roots of you polynom, for this you could look at the indication given by @MathGuy .
However if you want to stick with your method it is probably very hard because you have $3$ equations of degree $2$, so in the end you will have to solve an equation of degree $6$, which is impossible in general (but maybe this one is solvable)

It doesn't factorize over $\Bbb Q:$  it's the $5$-th cyclotomic polynomial. It factors over $\Bbb R.$  The primitive $5$-th roots of unity come in conjugate pairs.

You can write this as $x^2(t^2+pt+q)$ where $t=x+x^{-1}$. From there you get your factorization.

See:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2328207/complex-integration-int-infty-infty-fracx-1x5-1-dx?noredirect=1

See here for a genetal method to factor quartics, applied to exactly this one. The key is you have to have a rational root to a resolvent cubic equatiom, otherwise the factors are too unwieldy to use practically in computation or at all in geometric construction.

Beside using the roots of unity, the problem is simple if you guess or assume that $b=d=1$.
This leads to
$$a^2-a-1=0 \quad \implies a=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\sqrt{5}\right)$$
Therefore
$$x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1= \Big(x^2+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} x+1\Big)\Big(x^2+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2} x+1\Big)$$ Then partial fraction decomposition leads, as usual, to two logarithms and two arctangents. Using the bounds leads to the simple result.

Suppose the ground field is the complex field $\mathbb{C}$. Then
$$
1 + x + \dots + x^4 = \frac{x^5-1}{x-1}
$$
One primitive root of $x^5 - 1$ is $\omega_5 = e^{i \frac{2\pi}{5}}$. So the roots of $1 + x + \dots + x^4$ are $\omega_5, \omega_5^2, \omega_5^3, \omega_5^4$. Therefore,
$$
1 + x + \dots + x^4 = (x-\omega_5)\dots(x-\omega_5^4)
$$
Note that $\omega_5$ and $\omega_5^4$ are conjugate, so $(x-\omega_5)(x-\omega_5^4)=x^2 - (\omega_5 + \omega_5^4)x + 1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. Similarly, $(x-\omega_5^2)(x-\omega_5^3) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$.

The roots are the primitive fifth roots of unity.   They're $e^{2\pi ik/5}, k=1\dots 4.$
We get $(x^2-2\cos(2\pi/5)x+1)(x^2-2\cos(4\pi/5)x+1).$

Too long for a comment.
While the factorization of the denominator is immediate, I tried to calculate the integral as an contest student in rush. By residue theorem, the answer is
$$2\pi i\left(\frac1{4w^3+3w^2+2w+1}+\frac1{3w^4+2w^3+4w+1}\right)$$
Multiplying the denominators by their conjugates and taking the imaginaty parts of the terms in the paranthesis, we have
$$-2\pi\left(\frac{\sin2\alpha-2\sin\alpha}{30+30\cos2\alpha+40\cos\alpha}
+\frac{-2\sin2\alpha-\sin\alpha}{30+30\cos\alpha+40\cos2\alpha}
\right)$$
or
$$\frac{-4\pi\sin\alpha}{5\sqrt5}\left(\frac{2\cos\alpha-2}{\sqrt5+1}
+\frac{-4\cos\alpha-1}{\sqrt5-1}
\right)$$
$$=\frac{-4\pi\sin\alpha}{5\sqrt5}\left(\frac{\sqrt5-5}{2(\sqrt5+1)}
-\frac{\sqrt5}{\sqrt5-1}
\right)$$
$$=\frac{-4\pi\sin\alpha}{5\sqrt5}(-\sqrt5)=\frac{\sqrt2\sqrt{5+\sqrt5}\pi}5$$
Notes: $w=e^{\frac{2\pi i}5}$, $\alpha=72^\circ$, $\cos\alpha=\frac{\sqrt5-1}4$, $\cos2\alpha=-\frac{\sqrt5+1}4$, $\sin\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt5}}{2\sqrt2}$

And how do students do that in 5 minutes in front of the board... Are they ro bots?
